# Why does Maven Shared Assembly Plugin need the same dependency 2 times?

Tags: dependencies, shared, maven-assembly-plugin

I am using maven assembly plugin whereas I use an assembly file from another jar. Maven says that I need to add the specific package (which contains the assembly.xml) in the pom.xml of the other project under the section "maven-asssembly-plugin", so it knows where it can find the assembly.xml. It looks like this:

```
<build>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>mygroupid</groupId>
                <artifactId>myartifactid</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.1</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <configuration>
            <descriptorRefs>
                <descriptorRef>assembly</descriptorRef>
            </descriptorRefs>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

```
<dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>mygroupid</groupId>
    <artifactId>myartifactid</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

This definitely WORKS, however as you can see I need to add the same dependency TWICE, first for getting the assembly.xml, and second to get other files/classes/etc. from the package. Now I wonder if it's possible to add it only ONCE? (for better maintenance)

(I know I could configure the groupId/artifactId/version in a  tag, but I try to avoid that)

OR better: is it possible to access the assembly.xml from the other jar file WITHOUT actually adding the specific depedency in the maven-assemply-plugin Tag of the current project? (so that it just searches through every jar-file which is added as dependencies)

Comment: Confused. You are accessing assembly.xml from other jar? Why not write one for your own project. If it's imported that the reason it might be requiring the dependencies to be explicitly shown.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. The reason is, that I have multiple projects using all the same assembly configurations. Therefore I centrally "outsourced" the configuration in another jar file.